# Genymotion отказывается создавать виртуальную машину

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

Добрый день.
У меня приключилась такая неприятность. На системе установлен VirtualBox, позже установил Genymotion создал первый эмулятор без проблем работало все хорошо. Прошел месяц понадобилось создать эмулятор на SDK 21. Выбираю параметры все скачивается нормально, идет процесс установки, после сбрасывается и выводит сообщение.

- Failed to deploy virtual device.
- Unable to create virtual device.
- Failed to import OVA file.

Пробовал скачать файл без загрузчика браузером и подменить файл та же история. Антивирусник процесс не блокирует.

Comment: Обновите genymotion и VirtualBox

Comment: пробовал импортировать VM 4.4.4 на OVA файл. VirtualBox выдал ошибку сейчас обновляюсь.

Comment: обновился не помогло

Comment: это тоже не помогло http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945709/geny-motion-failed-to-import-ova получается заглушка можно создать только одну машину

Answer (score 0):

После долгих танцев с бубном и получения нулевого результата. Решил использовать родной эмулятор intellij idea.